# Numerical Value as a function of a numerical value and categorical value. R

Tags: r

I have a data set in R that i wish to Graph. 
I have been using ggplot to create graphs of a numerical value as a function of another numerical value. 
I now wish to create a graph that represents a numerical value as a function of both a numerical and a categorical value.

```
ggplot(data = data.set) +
      geom_point(aes(x = Numerical_1, y = Numerical_2)) +
      geom_point(aes(x = Numerical_1, y = Categorical_1))
```

I tried this and got
Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

What can I do?

Comment: Your plotting command makes no sense to me. Could you elaborate on what you're trying to do? Why do you want to show a categorical variable on the same scale and in the same plot as a numeric variable? Do you perhaps want to use different facets?

Comment: Try `ggplot(data = data.set) +
      geom_point(aes(x = Numerical_1, y = Numerical_2)) +
      geom_point(aes(x = Numerical_1, y = as.numeric(Categorical_1))) ` to tell ggplot to coerce categorical data as numeric for plotting purpose. I am your categorical data is integers.